# How to convert a list of str to the list of ints?

Tags: python, list, recursion

I want to convert a given input to the list of ints. I can't use : for, while, sum, map, reduce, filter, import, eval, sort, exec, compile and single.
Here is what I wrote:

```
def convert_int(my_line):
    i = len(my_line) - 1

    if i == 0:
        return int(my_line[0])
    else:
        return [int(my_line[i]), convert_int(my_line[:i])]

line = input().split()

print(convert_int(line))
```

With input:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

The output is:

```
[5, [4, [3, [2, 1]]]]
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate two lists, not embed the recursive result into a list.

```
def convert_int(my_line):
    if not my_line:
        return []
    else:
        return [int(my_line[0])] + convert_int(my_line[1:])
```

Comment: `i` isn't defined.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (without for, while, sum, map, reduce, filter, import, eval, sort, exec, compile and single as stated in the question):

```
line = '1 2 3 4 5'

line = line.split()
i = iter(line)
line[:] = iter(lambda: int(next(i)), None)
print(line)
```

Prints:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```